# Cannot include std::thread header in wxWidgets application

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, wxwidgets

I have the following code:

```
#include "wx\wx.h"

class BClient : public wxApp
{
   virtual bool OnInit();
   virtual int  OnQuit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(BClient)

bool BClient::OnInit()
{

    return true;
}

int BClient::OnQuit()
{

    return 0;
}
```

As soon I try to add the line

```
#include <thread>
```

I receive this errors:

> Error 10  error C2347: '__w64' : can not be used with type '__w64
>   unsigned __int64'
>
> Error 12  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ','
>
> Error 13  error C2059: syntax error : ','

The errors refer to this file: **c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\concrt.h**

So, for some reason, wxwidgets and std::thread doesn't mix together.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and is there a workaround for this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your MSVS installation. Here, adding `#include <thread>` line either before or after `#include <wx/wx.h>` one works without any problems.

Also, on a completely unrelated note, there is no `OnQuit()` in the base class, only `OnExit()`.

Comment: Thanks VZ for your response. The errors were generated only when stl thread header was included after wx\wx.h header. If I first include stl thread and then  wx\wx.h   the solution compiles fine. Don't know what could be wrong because Visual Studio 2013 was installed on a fresh windows copy.

Comment: As I wrote, it works here when including it after `wx/wx.h` too. Maybe you use some non-default options in wx `setup.h`? Or have some really old wx version? I really don't see how could it happen with wxWidgets 3.

Comment: Yes, my version of wxWidgets  is pretty old (2.6.2). I will make an upgrade in the near future. Thanks for the support, have a nice day.